# Custom Value refiners in SharePoint 2016 API

Tags: search, search-results, 2016, enterprise-search, refiner

We have SP 2016 On Premises Search . In our search results, When we search for any query- we have refiner that counts the number of items in the specified Range.

But, Is it possible to sum the values (Integer- Column is of Int type) rather than the count of items in the range.

Any Pointers to get aggregation of the refiner values using JavaScript will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new refiner and performing the aggregation (in your case summation) in JavaScript?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott  We are using Search REST API, through which we take JSON results and displaying it in client website, is this better way to do?

Comment: Either way, you have to perform the math. The query engine won't do it for you.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Could you please add pointers on how to do that aggregation using JS? I will try that out

Comment: You'd need to ask a developer, I do some dev but have not tried this.

Comment: If you have using the search REST API you should be returning Search results, but you add the column for each result on query success and display it. Can you show your code?